# Converting integer value to bits and storing it into a char array?

Tags: c

I am designing a Reliable data transmission over UDP, where in the UDP data buffer which is a character array and in my first 2 bytes of it I have to put bits like 00010000.... and so on and I want to know how to achieve this. Please let me know if you need any info, thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: You can assign an integer value to a `char` variable, as long as it doesn't overflow.  `00010000` is 16.

Comment: UDP is an octet-oriented protocol, you can't put bits in it. You somehow have to pack the bits into octets. The most obvious solution would be to split the bit stream into groups of eight bits and make the first bit of each group the most (or least, it's up to you) significant bit of the corresponding octet. In other words, you can represent `00010000` as the number 16.

Answer (score 1):

write a function of converting a numbers into an string ( character array ) 
steps : 
      1.divide a integer number by 2 and store the modulus value in a character array.
      2.subtract the quotient value with an integer and store the result in the same integer
      3. keep on doing the step 1 and 2  until the integer value becomes zero.

Hope that this would be the simple conversion program

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking, "How to convert an [u]int-stream into a byte-string?"

Then you can try this:

```
1. Pick next integer x = uint[i]
2. Get four bytes out of it as
 b4 = x & 0xFF000000
 b3 = x & 0x00FF0000
 b2 = x & 0x0000FF00
 b1 = x & 0x000000FF
3. Write the four bytes into the stream s, e.g.
 s << b4 << b3 << b2 << b1;
4. i += 1
5. Go to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

or use more generic function to write a single bit into buffer (char array)
`

```
void setBitAt( char* buf, int bufByteSize, int bitPosition, bool value )
{
    if(bitPosition < sizeof(char)*8*bufByteSize)
    {
        int byteOffset= bitPosition/8;
        int bitOffset = bitPosition - byteOffset*8;

        if(value == true)
        {
             buf[byteOffset] |=  (1 << bitOffset);
        }
        else
        {
             buf[byteOffset] &= ~(1 << bitOffset);;
        }
    }
}
```

`